# Programar Crontab

Tags: linux, crontab

Tengo un problema al querer programar una tarea crontab que permita ejecutarlo /programas/backups.sh todos penúltimos días del todos los meses del año (en una sola línea). A las 23.00 Horas Enviando un mail al término de la ejecución a la
cuenta root@suservidor.cl

no se si alguien tiene alguna referencia como poder programar este crontab

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Matías! ¿Qué has intentado? Dudo que encuentres un tutorial que cubra por completo el problema planteado, pero podrías comenzar resolviendo un paso cada vez.

Comment: Lo que mas me interesaría es el tema del penúltimo día del mes no si si tengo que validar con un calendario (cal) o tal vez dejarlo un día en especifico para no tener problemas el tema del email no me tiene preocupado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que también puedes hacer es correr la condición dentro de tu archivo crontab, es decir, algo así.

```
00 23 27-31 * * [ $(date -d +2day +\%d) -eq 1 ] && /programas/backups.sh
```

Es decir, "Si pasado mañana es un día 1, entonces hoy es el penúltimo día de este mes".

Que es semejante a lo que respondió @IamDavid salvo que de esta manera no te preocupas de si borras ese script en otra ocasión.

Tanto la opción de @IamDavid como la mía son parte de las posibilidades que se establece en `man cron(5)`.

> LIMITATIONS
>
> The crontab syntax does not make it possible to define all possible periods one  could  image  off.  For
>          example, it is not straightforward to define the last weekday of a month. If a task needs to be run in a
>          specific period of time that cannot be defined in the crontab syntaxs the best approach would be to have
>          the program itself check the date and time information and continue execution only if the period matches
>          the desired one.
>
> If the program itself cannot do the checks then a wrapper script would be required.  Useful  tools  that
>          could  be used for date analysis are ncal or calendar For example, to run a program the last Saturday of
>          every month you could use the following wrapper code:
>
> ```
> 0 4 * * Sat   [ "$(date +\%e)" = "`ncal | grep $(date +\%a | sed -e 's/.$//') | sed -e 's/^.*\s\([0-9]\+\)\s*$/\1/'`" ] && echo "Last Saturday" && program_to_run
> ```

### Update 1

Pensando en la opción de @IamDavid, sobre utilizar la sugerencia de un script para devolver un 0 o 1 dependiendo del día, se me ocurrió la idea de mejor hacer un script que contega eso, es decir, que lo incluya y así te podrías saltar que algún día, después de muchos, regreses a ver ese crontab y no recuerdes qué hacía.

Es decir, tu crontab va a estar definido de la misma manera:

```
00 23 27-31 * * /programas/backup.sh
```

Pero tu programa `backup.sh` tendría que tener esa característica al inicio. Algo así.

```
#!/bin/bash

PASADO_MANANA="$(date -d +2day +%d)" #No necesitas escapar el caracter %

#Documentacion, etc, etc
#Puedes utilizar comodamente el built-in [[ sin miedo a la portabilidad
[[ "$PASADO_MANANA" != "01" ]] && exit 
# Si pasado manana no es "01" entonces hoy no es el penúltimo día,
# entonces se sale del programa.
# Esto se ejecuta cada penúltimo día del mes, etc, etc.

#Resto del código de backups.sh
```

No lo he probado pero considero que de esta manera sería más cómodo, aunque quizás su desventaja es que dentro del archivo de crontabs carece de verbosidad respecto a su tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

he encontrado este link:
http://blogofsysadmins.com/tarea-cron-para-el-ultimo-dia-de-cada-mes

Lo que hace en esta página es ejecutar un script en que que mira si el día de mañana es un número inferior al día de hoy (es decir, si hoy es 31, mañana será día 1, por lo que hay un cambio de mes), de ser así devueve "true" y si no false.

Creo que podrías adaptarlo a tu problema cogiendo en lugar del número de mañana, el número de dentro de 2 días.

Espero que te sirva!